# Error creating a formset - That choice is not one of the available choices

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a mode Map1 with 2 fields, Im trying to initialize the formset using this Map1. When I initialize just with name and position, it does not get intialized, its asking for a id value but when given a id value I get the below error.

```
class Map1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    position = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), size=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('name', 'position'))      



modelformset = modelformset_factory(Map1, fields=('name', 'position')) 
>>> data = {
...          'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',  # the number of forms rendered
...          'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '1',  # the number of forms with initial data
...          'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',  # the max number of forms
...          'form-0-id': 1,
...          'form-0-name': 'germantown',
...          'form-0-position': '10,20',
...          }
>>> formset = modelformset(data=data)
>>> formset.errors
[{'id': ['Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']}]
```

If I remove the form-id, I get this error -

```
>>> data = {
...          'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',  # the number of forms rendered
...          'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '1',  # the number of forms with initial data
...          'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',  # the max number of forms
...          
...          'form-0-name': 'germantown',
...          'form-0-position': '10,20',
...          }
>>> formset = modelformset(data=data)
>>> formset.errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/premanandlakshmanan/Documents/django-contribute/django/django/forms/formsets.py", line 295, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Users/premanandlakshmanan/Documents/django-contribute/django/django/forms/formsets.py", line 343, in full_clean
    form = self.forms[i]
  File "/Users/premanandlakshmanan/Documents/django-contribute/django/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/premanandlakshmanan/Documents/django-contribute/django/django/forms/formsets.py", line 144, in forms
    for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
  File "/Users/premanandlakshmanan/Documents/django-contribute/django/django/forms/formsets.py", line 144, in <listcomp>
    for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
  File "/Users/premanandlakshmanan/Documents/django-contribute/django/django/forms/models.py", line 588, in _construct_form
    pk = self.data[pk_key]
KeyError: 'form-0-id'
```

Comment: *Do* you have a Map1 item with id 1?

Comment: please add a description of your problem

Comment: Added the description. @Dan: I'm initializing a new formset with the form

Comment: I don't know what that means. I think you're saying you're trying to create a new object, in which case why are you passing an ID?

Comment: Its expecting a id. not sure why, I have the given the error above..

Comment: Because you've said you have an initial form. But you don't, because you are creating entirely new items. I must say, I don't really understand a) why you are using formsets rather than just forms, or b) why you are doing all this from the console rather than a web page.

Comment: I meant Im trying to initialize a formset. Good question..Im trying to write a unit test case for a condition where a formset is initialized and the values are saved into the database.